# single variable regression vs. multi variable regression p values

Tags: multiple-regression, linear

If I have 2 variables which I performed single variable linear regression on and observed no significant p-values > 0.05 for either one, is it possible to get significant p-values in a multi-variable regression for them, even if unlikely?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Moreover, just try it.

This is easy to see in an ANOVA setting. If your outcome is a function of variable a, variable b and some error. A few simplifying assumptions:

- variables a and b are not correlated
- variable a accounts for 20% of the variance in your outcome, variable b accounts for 30%, the remaining 50% is error variance.

If you regress your outcome on variable a only, the error in this model also includes variable b. So you are comparing 20% signal from variable a to the remaining 80% "noise", it may fall short of statistical significance.

However, if you include both variables in your model, your noise is now 50%. So to test variable a, you're looking at 20% signal to 50% noise, this gives you a better chance of finding statistical significance. To test variable b, it's 30% to 50%, even better.

I think this is the easiest way to see how the scenario you describe is possible.